# Microk8s join the host name of the joining node does not resolve to the IP Refusing join (400)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

I tried to use `microk8s add-node` in first machine. and second machine, I tried to `microk8s join <>:<>/<> --worker` but it returns this:

> the host name of the joining node does not resolve to the IP Refusing join (400)

Comment: consider adding more info, like whats on those `<>`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to make sure the control plane node can also resolve the hostname of the workers.

Add on the `/etc/hosts` of the control plane node: e.g.:

```
192.168.0.10 workerName
```

Comment: This should be in the documentation! Thanks a lot. Nearly destroyed my keyboard

Comment: I found that adding the worker entry into the master control plane probably did help, but I also needed to restart the microk8s service on the master, which forces `microk8s join` to create a new token.

Comment: I am new to microk8s, and thus far I am of mixed opinions - the joining seems to be brittle, and the errors on the master are not helpful. But I am not convinced it will be easier with standard K8S!